# My computer has dual-boot on with two identical Windows 7, is it safe to remove one of them?

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot

[Boot configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCdjX.png)

[Image of current partitions in my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbEum.png)

Choosing one of those two Windows 7 in the boot manager doesn't make any difference, the files are all the same, changes between sessions are consistent.   As written in the title, is it safe to delete that Windows 7(\Windows)?

*PS: It'd take time to tell you guys the backstory of this, but basically this is the situation I ended up with. I want to remove the other Windows 7 because I don't feel certain about having that in my computer (would it take up space, or even cause future conflicts?), and the boot manager that appear at every startups is getting more annoying over time.*

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Longer answer: No guarantees something will not break. Even longer answer: we can't be sure. Try it and see.

Comment: I would remove the one on the logical partition.

Comment: @Moab I'm not even sure if it's on the logical partition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, The second entry can be deleted.

[Boot Manager : Delete a listed Operating system](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2288-windows-boot-manager-delete-listed-operating-system.html)

Option One of this tutorial.